# Time to loop using long and double

Tags: java, loops, primitive

Following piece of code is take different timing with `long` and `double`, not able to understand why there is the difference in the timing?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long j = 1000000000;
        double k = 1000000000;

        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int index = 0; index < j; index++) {

        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int index = 0; index < k; index++) {

        }

        long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long longTime = t2 - t1;
        long doubleTime = t3 - t2;
        System.out.println("Time to loop long :: " + longTime);
        System.out.println("Time to loop double :: " + doubleTime);
    }
```

Output:

> Time to loop long :: 2322
>
> Time to loop double :: 1510

`long` is taking longer time than `double`, I have `64 bit window operating` system and `64 bit Java`.

When I modified my code and add `casting` `long` and `double` to `int` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long j = 1000000000;
        double k = 1000000000;

        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int index = 0; index < (int)j; index++) {

        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int index = 0; index < (int)k; index++) {

        }

        long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long longTime = t2 - t1;
        long doubleTime = t3 - t2;
        System.out.println("Time to loop long :: " + longTime);
        System.out.println("Time to loop double :: " + doubleTime);
    }
```

The time got reduced but still there is the difference in the timing, but this time double is taking more time than long(opposite of first case)

Output:

> Time to loop long :: 760
>
> Time to loop double :: 1030

Comment: In your second example, you're simply testing if 1000000000 times casting a long to an int is faster than 1000000000 times casting a double to an int. Apparently, it is.

Comment: Good question, @Ankush! My answer is below, I hope it clears things up a bit. This question may be worth sticking in the Wiki, could be quite a good thought exercise for those wanting to understand the practical implications of different data types.

Comment: Micro benchmarking in the JVM is notoriously difficult. There are many things you need to think about, and even then the result may not mean much for a real-world application. The HotSpot compiler doesn't kick in with a such small number of iterations, you need to do warmup, etc. In any case, how many times did you run the test? The average of how many runs are you showing here?

Comment: Got to know that this both long and double are NON atomic i.e. reading will help is 2 step one of each 32 bit. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I ran about 20 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, a `long` is a 64-bit integer and a `double` is a 64-bit floating point number. The timing difference will likely be due to the difference in optimisation between integer arithmetic and floating point arithmetic in your CPU's ALU.

Secondly, the second time you run your application, in each for loop, the loop evaluates the stop condition every time, so you're casting from a long and double to an integer respectively on every iteration. If you precast the value to an integer value before the loop's condition then you should get more consistent times:

```
int j_int = (int) j;
for(int index = 0; index < j_int; index++) { /* Body */ }

int k_int = (int) k;
for(int index = 0; index < k_int; index++) { /* Body */ }
```

Comment: long is a 64-bit integer, otherwise I agree.

Comment: Correct, long and double both 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

In general, casting from `long` to `int` is simpler than from `double` to `int`.

The reason is that `long` and `int` are both whole numbers and represented in memory simply by their binary representation (and possibly one bit for the sign).
Casting from one to another is quite straightforward by just "cropping" or "extending" the memory area (and handling signs correctly).

However, `double` are [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) and their binary representation a bit more complicated, using sign, mantissa and exponent.
Casting from here to whole numbers thus is more complicated, as it requires conversion from one binary format to the other first.